# C++ lib for disk persistent FIFO queue of binary messages

Tags: c++, data-structures, persistence

Looking for C++ library or easy and robust combination of ones that will provide durable disk backed queue for variable sizes binary blocks.

My app is producing messages that are being sent out to subscribers (messages are variable sized binaries), in a case of subscribers failure or restart or networking issues I need something like circular buffer to queue them up until subscriber return. Available RAM is not enough to handle worst case failure scenario so I'm looking for easy way to offload data to disk.

In best case : set up maximum disk space like (100G) and file name, recover data after application restart, .pus_back() / .front() / .pop_front() like API, no performance drawback when queue is small (99.99% case), no need for strict persistence (fsync() on every message)

Average case : data is not preserved between restarts

Some combo of boost libs will be highly preferable

Comment: What you're describing is called virtual memory...

Comment: https://qpid.apache.org/components/cpp-broker/index.html